# Weird textview.setText() inside adapter result

Tags: android, dictionary, textview, android-arrayadapter, settext

In my app I'm passing to adapter (which extends ArrayAdapter>) such list: `List<Map<String, String>>`. Single record from this list looks like: `{received=true, text=Some sort of text}` Here's my getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Map<String, String> singleRecord = new HashMap<String, String>();
    singleRecord = records.get(position);
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(record_layout, null);
    }

    //To test get method I do:
    String to_put =  singleRecord.get(KEY_TEXT);
    Log.e("Adapter", to_put);
    ////

    TextView singleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.singleID);
    singleText.setText(singleRecord.get(KEY_TEXT));

    //viewHolder.singleText.setText(tekst);

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

As you can see I want my TextView to setText which my map contains with key: "KEY_TEXT"; To test if get method works fine I put it in Log and it looks right, but when I'm setting text of my textview to the same text I put in LogCat (text from the map) I'm not getting value for the key : "KEY_TEXT", I'm getting something which looks like: `{received=true, text=Some sort of text}` so it's simply one record converted to String. Does anybody has idea why this is happening ?

Comment: So how does the *actual* string look, that you're storing (as the value) inside your map?

Comment: Why not `return rowView`? I suspect that the superclass method may fill in the wrong text somehow. What does your `getItem()` do?

Comment: You're right I was returning wrong value, however that's what eclipse wrote when I hit ctrl+space with getView method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   Map<String, String> singleRecord = new HashMap<String, String>();
    View vi = convertView;
    singleRecord = records.get(position);
    vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.record_layout, null);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.singleID);

    tv1.setText(singleRecord.get(KEY_TEXT));

    return vi;

}
```